# Using sed on a shell scripts on multiple files

Tags: unix, shell, sed

Hello friendly computing people,

This is a two part question. I'm writing two shell scripts with the goal of doing a 'find and replace' in all the index.php files in a folder and its subfolders.

The first shell script is this:

```
echo "running on all directories…"

find . -name '*.php' -exec ./search_replace.sh {} \;
```

which then runs the file search_replace :

```
echo "running search and replace script..."

sed -e 's/http:\/\/ericbrotto.com/file:\/\/\/Users\/ericbrotto\/Documents\/Portfolio_CV_etc.\/Offline_Portfolio/g' index.php > index.htm
```

My problems/questions are these:

1. When I run the first script it echos "running search and replace script..." 13 times which makes sense because there are 13 index.php files in the folders. But the result is that only one file is completed i.e. the words are replaced and an new htm file is created only once.
2. Is there anyway to do this so that instead of creating a new .htm file based on the .php file, I can just have the same index.php file with the words replaced? In other words can they edit the file without having to create a new one.

Thanks so much,

Comment: If you use an alternate delimiter in `sed` you won't have to escape all those slashes: `sed -e 's|http://...|file://...|g`

Comment: @Dennis - this is one of the best sed hints - useful (as always) because of the ubiquity of the slash!

Comment: Over in the Perl world, we call that `http:\/\/` type of mess "Leaning Toothpick Syndrome".  Alternate delimiters are your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the full pathname is sent to your search_replace.sh, you could replace index.php with $1, index.htm with $1.htm and then

```
mv $1.htm $1
```

as the line after your sed

re: your comments

original

```
sed -e 's/http:\/\/ericbrotto.com/file:\/\/\/Users\/ericbrotto\/Documents\/Portfolio_CV_etc.\/Offline_Portfolio/g' index.php > index.html
```

the lines s/b

```
sed -e 's/http:\/\/ericbrotto.com/file:\/\/\/Users\/ericbrotto\/Documents\/Portfolio_CV_etc.\/Offline_Portfolio/g' $1 > $1.html
mv $1.html $1
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but after writing this to my second shell script, I got no results:sed -e 's/http:\/\/ericbrotto.com/file:\/\/\/Users\/ericbrotto\/Documents\/Portfolio_CV_etc.\/Offline_Portfolio/g' mv $1.htm $1

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec sed -i 's|http:\/\/ericbrotto.com|file:\/\/\/Users\/ericbrotto\/Documents\/Portfolio_CV_etc.\/Offline_Portfolio|g' "{}" +;
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this gives me the error: sed: 1: "./EricBrotto/berit/inde ...": invalid command code . Any ideas?

Comment: change your `s///` to `s|||`, then check and escape all your slashes again.